# I got an error while npm run build with Next.js and material-ui

Tags: next.js, material-ui, app-router

The error code is below.
What is the main reason of this error?
And what should I do to solve this?
**If I need to share more info, Please let me know.**
By the way, I use app router.

```
npm run build

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.3

Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './modifiers/index.js'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@mui/base/Popper/Popper.js
./node_modules/@mui/base/Popper/index.js
./node_modules/@mui/base/index.js
./node_modules/@mui/material/node/Modal/Modal.js
./node_modules/@mui/material/node/Modal/index.js
__barrel_optimize__?names=Box,Modal,TextField!=!./node_modules/@mui/material/index.js
./app/user/signin/signin-form.tsx

./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/popper.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './modifiers/index.js'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/index.js
./node_modules/@mui/base/Popper/Popper.js
./node_modules/@mui/base/Popper/index.js
./node_modules/@mui/base/index.js
./node_modules/@mui/material/node/Modal/Modal.js
./node_modules/@mui/material/node/Modal/index.js
__barrel_optimize__?names=Box,Modal,TextField!=!./node_modules/@mui/material/index.js
./app/user/signin/signin-form.tsx


> Build failed because of webpack errors
```

Comment: This error was solved!!!
But I still don't know whay it hapeened....
I solved by deleting node_module folder and package-lock.json
reference: [https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-module-not-found-cant-resolve-popper-js](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-module-not-found-cant-resolve-popper-js)